# how to Split a part of a string only without splitting the whole string in Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

```js
var a="hi;there;my;friend;"
document.write(a.split(';'))
/*result is :
["hi","there","my","friend",""]
*/
```

I just want to split the character ';' for the part of the string "hi;there"and to "my;friend"
and leaving the in between and the ending ';'
I can make  a function to do what i need but iam asking if there is easier way to do it ;
and thanks